# My NSBezierPath changes in a NSCFTimer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

When I draw this object it one times works but after that my path object (witch is NSBezierPath) changes in a NSCFTimer object.

```
- (void)draw {
    NSRect drawingbounds = [self drawingbounds];
    if(image == nil) {
        image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:drawingbounds.size];

        [image lockFocus];
        NSAffineTransform *transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
        [transform translateXBy:-drawingbounds.origin.x yBy:-drawingbounds.origin.y]; 
        [transform concat];
        [[NSColor redColor] set];
        [path stroke];

        [image unlockFocus];
        [image retain];
    }

    [image drawAtPoint:NSMakePoint(10.0, 10.0)
          fromRect: NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0)
         operation: NSCompositeSourceOver
          fraction: 1.0];

}

- (NSRect)drawingbounds {
    NSLog([path description]);
    return NSMakeRect(10.0, 10.0, 100.0, 100.0);
    return NSInsetRect([path bounds], -[path lineWidth] , -[path lineWidth]);
}
```

Comment: Oops the code element didn't work, sorry

Answer (score 1):

Please post the code where the `path` variable is created.

It sounds like the path object is being deallocated, which is why you're seeing another object (`NSCFTimer`) in its memory location. This will happen if you have not retained the `path` object correctly.

Comment: You can also use Instruments's Zombies template to see all the places the path is sent a `release` message from.